# Blazor Collapsible Cards

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm creating an app at the moment and I've been trying to set up collapsible cards and I'm having real trouble. I've made it work with my FAQ page but there's another page which is populated dynamically from a datasource so the solution I have for the FAQ page isn't going to work. Here is the FAQ page shortened:

```
@page "/faq"

<PageTitle>FAQ</PageTitle>

@using NewProgram.Data
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)</h1>
<div class="row" id="FAQSection">
    <div class="col-md-12 faq-container accordian" id="accordian" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="card card-widget card-outline">
            <a class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#FAQSection" href="#" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(() => { IsVisible1 = !IsVisible1; })">
                <div class="user-block">
                    <i class="fa-2x fa fa-question-circle-o" style="float: left; padding-right: 1rem"></i>
                    <span class="question-title">Question 1</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body collapse @(IsVisible1 ? "show" : "")">
                <div class="mb-2 question-desc">
                    <p>blah blah blah</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-widget card-outline">
            <a class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#FAQSection" href="#" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="@(() => { IsVisible2 = !IsVisible2; })">
                <div class="user-block">
                <i class="fa-2x fa fa-question-circle-o" style="float: left; padding-right: 1rem"></i>
                    <span class="question-title">Question 2?</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body collapse @(IsVisible2 ? "show": "")">
                <div class="mb-2 question-desc">
                    <p>blah blah blah</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected bool IsVisible1 { get; set; }
    protected bool IsVisible2 { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone can help me with this as at the moment there is a differnet bool for each question which seems pretty daft. I was just hoping that making use of Bootstrap this would just be a given but I've spent three hours so far trying a load of different things.

I've tried doing it straight in bootstrap using data-toggle and when I put href="#" in it just redirects back to the main page.

Comment: You should the code that you have now **for the page** you're having problems with. And your expected results.

Comment: Otherwise we can only assume a solution for you and it might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Blazor is about making life easier with components.

You can make a Component for the `<div class="card card-widget card-outline">` elements. Each component manages one (internal) boolean.

Parameters for `string Title` (Question 1) and `RenderFragment ChildContent` (`<p>blah blah blah</p>`)

Answer (score 0):

I've:

1. Created a Component for the card and simplified it to make the code clearer.
2. Created a record and list to demo getting data from a data source.
3. User a Guid to identify each card and used that to identify which card is currently selected [if any].

`AccordianCard.razor`

```cs
<div class="card card-widget card-outline">
    <div class="card-header question-title" @onclick="this.ChangeCollapse">
    @this.Title
    </div>
    <div class="@_cardBodyCss">
        <div class="mb-2 question-desc">
            @((MarkupString)this.Content)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@* Normally put this in a Component Css file *@
<style>
    .question-title {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Title { get; set; } = "Not Set";
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Content { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Guid SelectedUid { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public EventCallback<Guid> SetAsSelected { get; set; }

    private readonly Guid _uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private bool _collapsed => this.SelectedUid != _uid;
    private string _cardBodyCss => _collapsed
        ? "card-body collapse"
        : "card-body collapse show";

    private async void ChangeCollapse()
    {
        if (_collapsed)
        {
            await this.SetAsSelected.InvokeAsync(_uid);
            return;
        }

        await this.SetAsSelected.InvokeAsync(Guid.Empty);
    }
}
```

Demo Page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<h1>Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)</h1>
<div class="row" id="FAQSection">
    <div class="col-md-12 faq-container accordian">

        @foreach(var card in _contentList)
        {
            <AccordianCard Title="@card.Title" 
                  Content="@card.Content"
                  SetAsSelected="SetSelectedCard"
                  SelectedUid="_selectedCard" 
            />
        }

    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Guid _selectedCard = Guid.Empty;

    private Task SetSelectedCard(Guid uid)
    {
        _selectedCard = uid;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private List<ContentData> _contentList = new()
    {
        new("Question 1", "<p>blah blah blah</p>"),
        new("Question 2", "<p>blah blah blah</p>"),
    };

    public record ContentData(string Title, string Content);
}
```

Comment: For this one, I ended up just using Bootstrap Blazor and using an accordion which worked perfectly. I've ended up doing another page with individual cards and using custom classes for the collapse part which is pretty cool.